# _CastError (type 'XFile' is not a subtype of type 'File' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

how are you?

I'm developing a store management app and, when registering a product, I need its photo. But, when taking the picture in the emulator camera, nothing happens, I just realized that I have this _CastError. About XFile is not a File.

**Code snippet**

```
 ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("Câmera"),
            onPressed: () async {
              File image = await ImagePicker()
                  .pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera) as File;
              imageSelected(image);
            },
          )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd put this as a response to G H Prakash's answer, but the formatting isn't there then, so you'd use it like this in your code. Basically, you get it as an XFile, then load it as a normal file and use it for further processing.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text("Câmera"),
  onPressed: () async {
    XFile ximage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    
    // load the image as File
    File image = File(ximage.path);
    imageSelected(image);
  },
)
```

The reason ImagePicker uses XFiles is for compatibility with Flutter Web, so you could also look into integrating XFiles in your further processing workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the image picker was upgraded to use Xfile instead of File. To convert Xfile to File you can use:

```
File file = File( _imageFile.path );
```

You will need to add `import 'dart:io'` as well.

Comment: Okay, exactly where do I put it? And do I need to remove any lines from my code?

Comment: import 'dart:io' on top.